# Highlight xml validation error in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to highlight XML validation errors in notepad++? I have selected XML Tools -> Auto validate option. Some errors are caught and reported with line number, some without.

I.e. this validation error "The attribute 'blahblah' is not allowed." does not tell me where to locate the erroneous attribute.

My Visual Studio XML editor simply highlights validation issues. I can not achieve the same in npp.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Alex, Npp is a darn good piece of open-source code. Make sure you send this information to the developer. I have found him very responsive to bug fixes and feature requests. It may just be that the xml syntax file needs updating. But one thing is for sure -- if you don't report it -- it will never be addressed. That's how open-source works.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about Npp; in **SynWrite** app:

- install SynLint plugin (in Addons manager "Install")
- install XmlLint subplugin (in Addons manager), see its readme.txt
- call XML file
- call SynLint (menu Options-Plugins)